# Is there a way to force the use of auto_ptr to be a compile time error?

Tags: c++, gcc

Perhaps I’ve missed it, but I’ve searched for this topic but haven’t found an answer.

I’ve just spent quite a bit of time removing all auto_ptr occurrences from our code base and we don’t want it creeping back in.

To clarify for the perfectly reasonable comment questions: We still allow it but we want it completely eliminated by the time we fully switch to C++20. I've removed the c++20 tag since it was misleading.

Is there a way to prevent programmers from using it in the future? Not a warning but completely prevent it.

If possible, I am looking for a solution that would just address the instances of auto_ptr, not all deprecated warnings.

Comment: `auto_ptr` is removed in C++17. You have tagged the question C++20. You should get compile time errors without efforts.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr`should not exist in `C++20`. Do you use the `-pedantic-errors` flag?

Comment: Both clang and gcc still accept `auto_ptr` in C++20 pedantic mode but if you add `-Werror=deprecated-declarations` they won't.

Comment: Regarding "-Werror=deprecated-declarations", wouldn't that make all deprecated messages into errors not just those regarding auto_ptr? I am not sure that will fly with my team (though personally I am all for it.) Then again, I am not sure how many "deprecated" warnings there are so perhaps no big deal. I will try it it out first.

Comment: `git` pre-commit hook? CI test for warnings?

Comment: @BernieP If you add `-Werror` then all warnings will get treated as errors.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ha! I really like that but I know that won't fly with team! Maybe someday.

Comment: @tadman git pre-commit hook is an interesting suggestion. Not quite what I was looking for but might work.

Comment: Why would you want an error on one obsolete feature (`auto_ptr`) but not on another?   As a general rule, if two different features are obsolete (say, in a specified standard and later) then using either feature is equally problematical.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the feedback. Though I really wanted a solution that would address just auto_ptr warnings, I’ve accepted @Jesper 's response as the answer since it provides the most detail on the issue in general. It will be useful to my team in the short term. Hopefully this post will help others.

Comment: @Peter For similar reason as our situation with the auto_ptr: we need to be aware that there are issues via the warnings but it may take time to address them. We don't want to stop all builds altogether until we have time to get rid of the existing occurrences in the code. Once we have eliminated a warning from our code, we do make it an error to prevent it creeping back in.

Comment: @BernieP While I'm sympathetic to your view that you need to keep builds working while you fix issues, I'd say that maybe you should "stop the press" while you fix the warnings, since (in my experience) most warnings are actually real bugs in your product, and they *will* bite you eventually...

Comment: @jesper It really isn't feasible. We are talking over 3 million lines of commercial code. We aren't ignoring them, as I say, we are aggressively eliminating them. But in the interim, development and support must continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`auto_ptr` was deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17, so one easy way to turn use of `auto_ptr` into an error would be to compile your code as C++17 (or later).
Not all compilers actually removed `auto_ptr` - leaving it in for backwards compatibility, but `GCC` for example emits a warning that can be turned into an error.

To turn on C++17 standards compliant mode in the `GCC` compiler, build with the `-std=c++17` flag. To turn the deprecation warning into an error, add the `-Werror=deprecated-declarations` flag.

Example (`foo.cc`):

```
#include <memory>
int main() {
    std::auto_ptr<int> p;
}
```

Compile as: `g++ -std=c++17 -Werror=deprecated-declarations foo.cc`

Result:

```
foo.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
foo.cc:4:8: error: ‘template<class> class std::auto_ptr’ is deprecated: use 'std::unique_ptr' instead [-Werror=deprecated-declarations]
    4 |   std::auto_ptr<int> p;
      |        ^~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/13.1.1/memory:78,
             from foo.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/13.1.1/bits/unique_ptr.h:65:28: note: declared here
   65 |   template<typename> class auto_ptr;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~
cc1plus: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: Though I really wanted a solution that would address just auto_ptr warnings, I’ve accepted this response as the answer since it provides the most detail on the issue in general. It will be useful to my team in the short term. Hopefully this post will help others.

Answer (score 4):

GCC warns about it:

```
warning: 'template<class> class std::auto_ptr' is deprecated: use 'std::unique_ptr' instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

`-Werror=deprecated-declarations` will turn this into an error.